# Which is more appropriate here regarding in names: Junior or the 2nd?

Tags: names, surnames

I am from Philippines and I had a childhood friend named after his father, Cipriano Reyes, so my friend's name is Cipriano Reyes II.

But as far as I know, when a child was named after his father the title would be Junior (Jr.).

Does it mean that my friend's title is wrong? Will it affect the name of my friend's son if he will name it after him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the first son named after his father is "Junior" thus making his father "Senior." If Jr. names his son the same name, then Jr. becomes the II, and his son is the III. So "Frank" + (namesake) son = "Frank Sr." and "Frank Jr." Then Frank Sr. + (namesake) son + (namesake) grandson = Frank Sr. and Frank II and Frank III. And so forth. The "Junior" is dropped and becomes II (the second) when the III (the 3rd) namesake is born.

Comment: Does it mean that the father of my friend made a wrong title for him?

Comment: I believe this applies even when the generations are not consecutive.

Comment: @JaegerJay - personally, I wouldn't call it "wrong" even if it's technically incorrect. It seems to me it's a social custom or some such, _not_ a law.  I for one, definitely reserve the right to name my children anything I *** well please!

Comment: Well said, W9WBH :)

Comment: Changing titles is a social custom, but that doesn't mean that these titles can't be a matter of law.  Name your kid Bozo Barrett, III on his birth certificate, and "III" is part of his legal name.  This hardly ever matters in the US, since with a few minor exceptions you may call yourself whatever you want.  For formal occasions (like signing a contract), you may need some form of name affidavit.

Comment: @W9WBH In the US, you may disable your child with any name you wish to burden the tyke with.  But in some jurisdictions, that freedom will not extend to the kid's surname.

Comment: @deadrat First, let me just say that anyone who would even _consider_ naming their child Bozo for instance, should be fined and legally barred from ever being allowed to name anyone or anything -even their pets! Seriously though, the topic here is regarding the custom of adding suffixes to the surnames of family members who share the same names. You can have a string of John Q. Jones in a family, with none of them adding Jr., Sr., II, III, etc. There is _no law_ that requires this.

Comment: You are correct that if your parents put a suffix on your birth certificate, it's part of your formal given name. But that's hardly binding, if you care to drop it (or add one for that matter.) I have signed contracts that required a Notary Public, but that is a witness to your signature, not an affidavit of your actual name per se.

Comment: With marriages, divorces, remarriages, blended & reblended families today -here in the US anyway, keeping track of name changes could make one dizzy. When I got married, I decided my middle initial "J" which was for Jean (and I never cared for it much) would now stand for my maiden name Johnston. It was rather handy I thought, that it was still the same initial, but I did nothing formal. Years later, I needed to get a replacement SSN card because my original was lost eons ago, I simply wrote Johnston in place of Jean. In fact, I hadn't bothered to change it to my married name until then either

Comment: Although I guess I did update my DL. The point is that your social security number never changes. On my mom's death certificate her AKAs included her birth name; then her name with another middle name added (some catholic thing I think); then first married; second married; and included in all these were a few variations of "Alice" (Alyce, Alis) as however she had preferred over the years. But there isn't anything illegal about it, your Soc. never changes.  All I'm trying to say is that you don't have to be so tightly bound to the letter of your name nowadays, and whether you do or do not

Comment: use, drop, or add Jr. or II or whatever, you have choices. (Good thing for those kids who were/are "disabled" with awful names or parents with evil senses of humor!) But back to JaegerJay's query, it's almost a moot point whether his friend's dad named him with Jr. or II, inasmuch as his position in the order of a line of family namesakes does _not_  change. He is always the second in the line, if there more after him, or if he's the last and only one. Junior and II are the _same_: he is the first son named for his dad.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Kennedy family tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kennedy_family).

Joseph P. 'Joe' Kennedy Sr. (1888–1969) begat Joseph Patrick Kennedy Jr. (1915–1944).  But, Robert Francis 'Bobby' Kennedy (1925–1968), brother of Joe Jr, has a son: Joseph Patrick Kennedy II (b. 1952).  He begat Joseph Patrick Kennedy III (b. 1980).

The difference between the Jr and II is that the Jr is a direct descendant of Joe Sr, but II is a grandnephew of Joe Sr.

Use Jr for direct descendants and II if you are not a direct descendant, but in the same family.